# Type Variables in Instance Decelerations (Aeson)

Tags: haskell, instances, aeson, type-variables

I have JSON data that may either look like this

```
{
"items": [Day],
"pageCount": Int,
"totalCount": Int
}
```

or this

```
{
"items": [Order],
"pageCount": Int,
"totalCount": Int
}
```

I've been trying to create a data type for the unvaried fields for use with FromJSON, but I haven't been able to find the proper way to do it, while going through a variety of errors. This is my code in its current state

```
--{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
--{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
--{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import           Data.Aeson

data Typed = Typed {typeID::Int,name::String} deriving (Show,Eq)
data Day =  Day {orderCount::Int,lowPrice::Float,highPrice::Float, avgPrice:: Float,volume::Int,date::String}
data Order = Order {price::Float,isBuy::Bool,location::Typed} deriving (Show,Eq)
data Market a = Market {items::a,pageCount::Int,totalCount::Int} deriving (Show,Eq)
-- Can be either Market [Order] or Market [Day]
instance FromJSON (Market a) where
  parseJSON (Object x) = Market <$> x .: "items" <*> x .: "pageCount" <*> x .: "totalCount"
instance FromJSON Order where
  parseJSON (Object x) = Order <$> x .: "price" <*> x .: "buy" <*> x .: "location"
instance FromJSON Typed where
  parseJSON (Object x) = Typed <$> x .: "id" <*> x .: "name"
instance FromJSON Day where
  parseJSON (Object x) = Day <$> x .: "orderCount" <*> x .: "lowPrice" <*> x .: "highPrice"
    <*> x .: "avgPrice" <*> x .: "volume" <*> x .: "date"
```

And this is the current error I get

```
No instance for (FromJSON a) arising from a use of ‘.:’
    Possible fix:
      add (FromJSON a) to the context of the instance declaration
    In the second argument of ‘(<$>)’, namely ‘x .: "items"’
    In the first argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely ‘Market <$> x .: "items"’
    In the first argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely
      ‘Market <$> x .: "items" <*> x .: "pageCount"’
```

Comment: Do what it tells you, add `FromJSON a` to the context: `instance FromJSON a => FromJSON (Market a) where ...`

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know what it meant, nor did I think it would be that simple. This is my first attempt at using instances, and I just got rid of several "Couldn't match type" errors relating to that instance, so I thought it would be more complicated than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are two issues here. The first is the compilation error: you claim that you have an instance for `Market a` which should mean you know how to parse the JSON serialization of a market for any choice of `a`, but this isn't really possible because you want to parse something of type `a` in order to price the contents of the `price` field.

We restrict our attention to only consider possible `a`'s that we know how to parse by adding a constraint to our instance declaration:

```
instance FromJSON a => FromJSON (Market a) where
  ...
```

and now all is well. There's another problem though, the way that we've implemented `FromJSON` we see that it's riddled with nonexhaustive matches! Try running this with `-Wall` to see GHC complain at us for it. Now the problem is that each `parseJSON` will actually fail with an exception (not a parsing failure, like a "blow up the whole program" failure) if fed something other than an `Object`. This means that we get poor behaviour like

```
λ> decode "1.0" :: Maybe Typed
*** Exception: /home/jozefg/scratch/Aeson.hs:(24,3)-(25,39): Non-exhaustive patterns in function parseJSON
```

In order to fix this we can just add another clause explicitly failing in all the other cases. The more production-y solution might be to not handwrite these instances since they're all pretty straightforward and instead use aeson's support for generics for example. Here's the fixed instance for `Order` for example where I've just added an extra clause

```
instance FromJSON Order where
  parseJSON (Object x) =
    Order <$> x .: "price" <*> x .: "buy" <*> x .: "location"
  parseJSON _ = mempty
```